# XML parsing with XMLtree or MINIDOM

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, minidom

I have a xml file, and in the middle of it I have a block like this:

```
...
<node id = "1" >
  <ngh id = "2" > 100 </ngh>
  <ngh id = "3"> 300 </ngh>
</node>

<node id = "2"> 
  <ngh id = "1" > 400 </ngh>
  <ngh id = "3"> 500 </ngh>
</node>
...
```

and trying to get

```
1, 2, 100
1, 3, 300
2, 1, 400
2, 3, 500
...
```

I found a similar question and did the following

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('file.xml')
nodelist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('node')

for s in nodelist:
    print s.attributes['id'].value)
```

is there a way to get i get the values between  tags (i.e. 100, 300, 400) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an inner loop over `ngh` elements:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse('file.xml')
nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('node')

for node in nodes:
    node_id = node.attributes['id'].value
    for ngh in node.getElementsByTagName('ngh'):
        ngh_id = ngh.attributes['id'].value
        ngh_text = ngh.firstChild.nodeValue

        print node_id, ngh_id, ngh_text
```

Prints:

```
1 2 100
1 3 300
2 1 400
2 3 500
```